# How to use previous commit messages when composing new one?

Tags: git, git-bash

I staged changes, I run `git commit`, I see:

```
 
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   ...
#   ...
```

I need to see `git log -10 --oneline` output here as well. How to do it?

Comment: Do you want the output prefixed with "#", or do you want it to actually go in the commit message?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch I need messages to copy something from them. It doesn't matter how it will look.

Comment: Well if you know the commit you want to copy from, use `git commit -c <commit> --res` as Klas suggests. Otherwise use my answer if you want to preserve the stuff that usually comes up in the editor, or his alternative 2 if you don't.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch thank you a lot! My question is answered. I'll mark your answer at soon as I try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in a file called `prepare-commit-msg` in your `.git/hooks` directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
temp=`cat $1`
git log -10 --oneline > $1
echo "$temp" >> $1
```

Comment: When commit is supplied with message using `-m`, `-F` or `-c` option, `git log` output is appended to commit message. To append `git log` output only when no message is supplied and Vim is opened, hook should do its work only when second parameter is empty. I used `case $2,$3 ; ,) ... ;; esac`. Also, I added `# ` to each line.

Answer (score 2):

### Alternative 1, using command line flags

This will bring up the previous commit message in the configured git editor

```
git commit -c HEAD --res
```

### Alternative 2, using Git hooks

If you definitely want ten messages, you can use `the prepare-commit-msg` [Git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Put the following line as the content of the `prepare-git-commit-msg` file in the `.git/hooks` folder.

```
#!/bin/sh
git log -10 --oneline >> $1
```

It will add the last ten messages to the template for the commit message

Comment: Thank you, second approach is what I need. Unfortunately, I cannot mark both answers.